# Laravel - Accessing, Manipulate and Looping Through Pivot Table

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, `users` and `like_categories` which has `many-to-many` relationship. The `pivot table` is called `like_category_user`. After inserting two users data into the `db`, here is my `pivot table` look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMr8x.png

I want to count the `amount` for each of the different like `category` for each `user` and store it in `object array` like this:

```
[
    {
        "User Id": 1,
        "Like Categories": [
            {
                "Category": "Chinese Restaurant"
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Korean Restaurant"
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Fast Food Restaurant"
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Italian Restaurant"
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse Restaurant"
                "Amount": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "User Id": 2,
        "Like Categories": [
            {
                "Category": "Thai Restaurant"
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Kebab Shop"
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Pizza Place"
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse"
                "Amount": 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried to store the data from the db into an object array based on above format. But the output is not how i wanted it to be.
My code:

```
public function showUserLikesData() {

        $users = User::all();

        $counter = 0;
        $countUser = 0;
        $countThatCategory = 0;
        $categoryName = '';

        foreach($users as $user) {

            $userLikesData[$countUser]['User Id'] = $user->id;

            foreach ($user->likeCategories as $likeCategory) {

                 $categoryName = $likeCategory->pivot->category_name;

                foreach ($user->likeCategories as $likeCategory) {
                    $checkCategoryName = $likeCategory->pivot->category_name;

                    if ($categoryName == $checkCategoryName) {
                           $countThatCategory++;
                    }
                }

                $userLikesData[$countUser]['Like Categories'][$counter]['Category'] = $categoryName;
                $userLikesData[$countUser]['Like Categories'][$counter]['Amount'] = $countThatCategory;

                $countThatCategory = 0;

                $counter++;
            }
            $countUser++;
            $counter=0;
        }

        return $userLikesData;
    }
```

The `object array` i get:

```
[
    {
        "User Id": 1,
        "Like Categories": [
            {
                "Category": "Chinese Restaurant",
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Korean Restaurant",
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Korean Restaurant",
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Fast Food Restaurant",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Italian Restaurant",
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse",
                "Amount": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "User Id": 2,
        "Like Categories": [
            {
                "Category": "Thai Restaurant",
                "Amount": 1
            },
            {
                "Category": "Kebab Shop",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Kebab Shop",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Kebab Shop",
                "Amount": 3
            },
            {
                "Category": "Pizza Place",
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Pizza Place",
                "Amount": 2
            },
            {
                "Category": "Steakhouse",
                "Amount": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Wait .. whats the difference between the outputs?

Comment: @AntonyMN there is some redundant key. Probably because of how i loop

Comment: Maybe what I meant to ask is ... whats the difference between what you are getting and what you want? That is, explain what you REALLY WANT TO DO, maybe there is an easier way to do it, or a laravel function available

Comment: @AntonyMN i have edited my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the same output just replace this

```
$users = User::all();
```

to

```
$users = User::all()->toArray();
```